handle3DSMethodCallback.do downloaded by Chrome during a card paynent
While making a payment in a Chrome incognito tab, I was prompted to download a file.
The file downloaded was a document named handle3DSMethodCallback.do.
I have had ongoing security issues with my Google account, my Apple account, and numerous apps, such as Facebook and Instagram. Is this something I should be concerned about?
Any advice would be appreciated. Please don’t hesitate to call me paranoid either!
Thanks in advance.
N/A
I am a civilian, have never seen this happen before.

Edit to add: “Period” was not supposed to be in that sentence. Payment was with a card.
